# Automorphisms on $(\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, $\cdot)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Are there any multiplicative bijections from $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ onto itself apart from the identity?

Playing around I can see that any multiplicative isomorphism $f$ must preserve zero, the identity matrix and inverses (i.e., $f(A^{-1}) = f(A)^{-1}$), and simple facts expressed via first order sentences with the product (like "any invertible matrix must be mapped to an invertible matrix"), but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Inner automorphisms, such as $X\mapsto A^{-1}XA$ for a fixed matrix $A$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Of course! Lovely. Thanks